# Why is v lowercase and D uppercase in $v=H_0D$?

Tags: observational-astronomy, astrophysics, expansion, mathematics, hubble-constant

Why is v almost always written in lowercase and D in uppercase in $v=H_0D$?

OK, v is in lowercase, as usual, but then why is D in uppercase? What's so different/special about it?

In my physics school text/book and Wikipedia it is written as v=H0D, and I always assumed that was the correct form. Yes I have seen it written as v=H0d, but I always thought that was a mistake. I think I assumed that it was D because both my sources pointed out that it was a proper distance, as opposed to a co-moving distance, I suppose. I cannot believe it is just arbitrary. Physics symbols are case sensitive. Was v=Hod considered too confusing!?

Comment: It's only that way becasue that if how you typed it.  If you typed V= H0d then the V is uppercase and the d is lowercase.

Comment: @James K: No it isn't! It is almost always written as v=H0D. Just Google it.

Comment: However your (English) words are written like this and not "Hauewwer juhr wörds ahr not written laik sis" - it's all a matter of convention and making communication easy. A decent source ALWAYS tells the reader what each symbol in an equation is supposed to mean. Just google it. v as in velocity, D as in distance, H as in Hubble. capitalization to not confuse with V for volume or d for ... also distance. why ever.

Comment: related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/36298/where-do-the-symbols-lambda-and-beta-come-from-for-celestial-latitude-and/37063#37063

Comment: It's moderately common to use *d* for diameter and *D* for distance, but this is merely a common (not universal) convention. Someone using *d* for distance is not making a "mistake".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is built on a false premise and $v = H_0 D$ is not a universal convention.

If a child asked you, you could point them first to the [BBC bitesize revision notes](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zphppv4/revision/3) on Hubble's law, which uses $v = H_0 d$.

Then [hyperphysics notes](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/hubble.html), which uses $v = H_0 r$.

(These were the two of the first three non-pdf hits I got when I googled "Hubble's law")

I would then explain to the child that any algebraic symbol can have any meaning you choose to attach to them.

Comment: Ye's and no. Ye's I just Googled it and I was surprised by how many hits had it as v=H0d but I always assumed that was a mistake, coz my school physics text/book and Wikipedia have it as v=H0D. I think I assumed it was D because it was a proper distance, as opposed to a comoving distance, which should be d? I cannot believe it's just arbitrary.

Comment: @CuriousCat - well, convention is not the same as arbitrary. And there is no entity that dictates symbol usage and holds people to it.

Comment: @Jon Custer: Really!? Oh, come on. Physics symbols are case sensitive, and I have only ever seen F=ma, for example, written as such. Never as f=MA.